# "Bug": After using jquery's focus() method on an input field I can't move the focus cursor with the mouse cursor

Tags: jquery, input, html-table, cursor, focus

It only reacts to the keyboard arrows, not to the mouse. But I want to skip the focus cursor to where I click at. This is the function I use:

```
$(function () {
$("td").not(".cellEditing").dblclick(function () {
    var OriginalContent = $(this).text();

    $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
    $(this).html("<input type='text' id='textinput' size='100' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
    $(this).children().first().focus();

    $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var newContent = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().text(newContent);
            $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
        }
    });

    $(this).children().first().blur(function () {
        $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
        $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
    });
});
});
```

Got that code from here: http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-an-editable-html-table-with-jquery/27425

Is there a way the user can move the cursor in the input fields via mouse?

P.S.: Found out that it works perfect normally, but with this code in my script it doesn't work anymore:

```
$(function () {
$("#editableTable tbody.sortable").sortable({
    cursor: "move",
    //items: 'tr.sortable-row',
    stop: function () {
        oddRowColor();
    }
});

$("#editableTable tbody.sortable").disableSelection();

});
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this bug in a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vbmbD/2/ - done. But works as it should there but not for me :(

Comment: Then it's most likely that the issue lies elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Yep, deleting that "sortable"-code above it works. Still have enough problems with my editable table :D